# asp.net regex help

Tags: asp.net, regex

Hi ive got this regular expression and that extracts numbers from a string

```
string.Join(null,System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split(expr, "[^\\d]"));
```

so eg, the format of my string is like this strA:12, strB:14, strC:15

so the regex returns    121415

how can I modify the expression to return
12,14,15 instead, any suggestions please

Comment: Do you understand the code you just wrote?

Comment: Thanks I understand the code, the problem is it sort of works but not quite as I get this  2,,,,,,,,,1,,,,,2,,,,,,,, as opposed to 2,1,2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `String.Join`, which joins an array of strings into a single string, separating each element by the `separator` parameter.

Since you're passing `null` as that parameter, it doesn't put anything between the strings.

You need to pass `", "` instead of `null` to separate each string with `,`.

Comment: Thanks I understand the code, the problem is it sort of works but not quite as I get this  2,,,,,,,,,1,,,,,2,,,,,,,, as opposed to 2,1,2

Comment: Change the regex to `@"[^\d]+"`.